# Concatenate using vba - visible cells only?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to concatenate a number of cells from one sheet into another and then copy that formula down to the last row.

However the sheet that I'm looking to concatenate from has hidden cells. So currently this is messing up my results on the target sheet.

Is there a way to fix this so it only picks up visible cells?

```
Dim FitRng As Range, Lastrowteam As Long

Lastrowteam = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Pipeline simplified").Select
Range("W7").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=CONCATENATE(Pipeline!R[2]C[7],"" "",Pipeline!R[2]C[8],"" "",Pipeline!R[2]C[9],"" "",Pipeline!R[2]C[10])"

Set FitRng = Range("W7:W" & Lastrowteam).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
FitRng.FillDown
```

Comment: What does "messing up my results" actually stand for? Note that unqualified `Worksheet` member calls (`Cells`, `Range`) are implicitly referring to whatever worksheet is the `ActiveSheet`. Are the results being written to the wrong sheet? Try qualifying `Cells` and `Range` calls with a specific `Worksheet` object reference. Or it's filling down to hidden rows? Try assigning to `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: I'm picking up results from hidden cells when i want to avoid them. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you based on code provided in your question:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim DataCell As Range
    Dim aResults() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Pipeline Simplified")   'Sheet where you are getting the concatenated data
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")                'Sheet where the results will be output
    Set rDest = wsDest.Range("A2")                      'Cell on destination sheet where output results will start

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rData = wsData.Range("G2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rData Is Nothing Then Exit Sub   'No visible cells
    If rData.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub      'No data

    ReDim aResults(1 To rData.Cells.Count, 1 To 1)
    For Each DataCell In rData.Cells
        i = i + 1
        aResults(i, 1) = DataCell.Value & " " & DataCell.Offset(, 1).Value & " " & DataCell.Offset(, 2).Value & " " & DataCell.Offset(, 3).Value
    Next DataCell

    rDest.Resize(UBound(aResults, 1)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: This works to concatenate the values in visible cells, but changes OP's logic from computed/formula to plain values - which *might* work for OP's needs, but they should know that modifying any of the individual concatenated values will no longer recalculate the result column (i.e. macro needs to be re-executed to update the values).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That is a good point, I hadn't considered that.  I interpreted the formula going into column W as a placeholder for the concatenated values since that formula was being put on the same worksheet as the data it's joining, and in the question the OP specifies that he wants the results to be on a different sheet, so this just skips that (admittedly, interpreted) middle step.  If it does need to result in a formula, I'll definitely update the answer.

Comment: Thanks Tiger - will try this! Just so I'm aware (as i'm trying to get better) - which is the row that refines the cells to concatenate?

Comment: Subscript out of range error - aResults(i, 1) = DataCell.Value & " " & DataCell.Offset(, 1).Value & " " & DataCell.Offset(, 2).Value & " " & DataCell.Offset(, 3).Value. Is this because DataCell isn't defined?

Comment: @SuperLoz I am unable to reproduce that error.  It should only happen if aResults isn't large enough for rData, but that should never be the case since it's defined based on rData.  I'd need to see what your data looks like to try to reproduce that error.  In the meantime, you could try changing the `ReDim` line to be `ReDim aResults(1 to 65000, 1 to 1)` and see if that helps.